# Python 4.7: How to count the frequency of specific value in array

Tags: python, numpy

Basically I have a list with 250 elements, some of them are 1 some 2 and some 3. How do I get a variable that represents the number of ‘1’s ?

Comment: Python 4.7? Is this the number of an exercise? Surely not the language version ...

Comment: Python 4.7? You may be asking from the future. However, we do not do homeworks.

Comment: Just use the `count`-method from class `list`: `[1,1,2,1].count(1)` for example

Comment: Do not be too harsh. First time asking a question. Give him some advice.

Comment: Answered and someone please edit the title and write 2.7

Comment: @alexisdevarennes Leave the title as it is. Editing it will make all these comments off-topic.

Answer (score 6):

This exists natively in Python

```
from collections import Counter

A = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
B = Counter(A)
```

outputs `Counter({1: 5, 3: 5, 4: 4, 2: 3})`

Comment: Nice way to do it!

Comment: Would upvote, but out of points. Still leaving my answer so he gets the logic behind it.

Comment: yours is better in the case that a human readable result is needed anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

## I assume this will still be the case in python 4.7

Jokes aside, this will work in Python 2.7 (and 3 etc)

Using count():

```
your_list = [1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
distinct_values = set(your_list)
if len(distinct_values) == len(your_list)
    print('All values have a tf count of 1')
else:
    for distinct_value in distinct_values:
        print('%s n occurences: %s' % (distinct_value, str(your_list.count(distinct_value))))
```

Using in (Solution provided by @nfn neil via comments):

```
your_list = [1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
di = {}
for item in your_list:
    if item in di:
        di[item] += 1
    else:
        di[item] = 1
print(di)
```

benchmarks running both variants 300 times with a list of 500 000 items:

The runtime for using_in took 18.3120000362 seconds to complete

The runtime for using_count took 743.9941547110 seconds to complete

Benchmark code:

https://pastebin.com/dWS8UH7c

Comment: Calling `count` in a loop requires a separate pass over the input for every `count` call. It's catastrophically slow for inputs with a lot of distinct items.

Comment: Catastrophically means its time complexity in O(n) where n is length of list.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure this would be O(n^2) worst case scenario.  Let's say we have a list of unique values, then we are looping through each value in the `list`.  Then we have to loop (again) over each item to get the count of the item for every item in the list.

Comment: @alexisdevarennes While I do appreciate the gesture, it doesn't fix the underlying issue.  What if every value is unique in the list, except there is 1 duplicate.  Still it would have to iterate over it in an n^2 manner.

Comment: @nfnneil I was talking about the `count()` method time complexity. I forgot to write `count()`. You are right. `else` block time complexity is O(n^2) in the worst case scenario.

Comment: @alexisdevarennes Here is a similar version with a time complexity of O(n):  https://pastebin.com/LiP93Buj .  Note: `item in di` is O(1).

Comment: @nfnneil I added your version, I hope that is OK

Comment: I also did some benchmarks

Comment: https://pastebin.com/S8X2g2tm

Comment: You may want to automatically generate a much larger list of random numbers to get a more accurate read.  But, anyway,  good answer, upvoted.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dWS8UH7c